# Flutter & Firestore : How do I get all of the DocumentID from Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, document

How do I get all of the DocumentID from Firebase and put them into a list.

```
Stream <List<String>> getMaterial(BuildContext context) {
    final CollectionReference materialColection =
        Firestore.instance.collection('materials');

   return ???????;
  }
```

other file

```
List<String> _material = [-------]
```

I'm looking forward to hearing from you. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this,

```
Future <List<String>> getMaterial(BuildContext context) async {

     List<String> ids =[];

    final CollectionReference materialColection =
        Firestore.instance.collection('materials');

    final result = await materialColection.get();  //getDcouments() for < firebase: ^0.14
      
     result.docs.forEach((doc){
          ids.add(doc.id) //doc.documentId for < firebase: ^0.14
      });


   return ids;
  }
```

This will return the list of ids of the document each time you call the function.

Alternatively, if you want to listen to the stream, it would be best to Warp it in a `StreamBuilder()` and extract the document ids within the widget

Comment: I did and I get the info I wanted. But an exception occurs. Why is that?

Comment: `I/flutter (13132): Another exception was thrown: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0`

Comment: Is your collection empty by any chance?

Comment: My collection has about 5 documents. But each documents is empty. Then I added some value but still the same.

Comment: Then, it should work, check for collecftion name, usually, there can be a whitespace, try deleting to check name